# FTP write access broken after updating to MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1

Tags: ftp, macos-sonoma

I can't upload files to my FTP server. The connection either times out, or uploads extremely slow (a few bytes per seconds). I suspect there's a problem with the firewall, but even switching it off doesn't change anything.

I'm using ftp on the command line. Another machine I running on MacOS 13 yet can still write the the ftp server, so I suspect something happened between September 20, 2023 and now. The only major change I remember is updating to MacOS 14.1.1.

How can I solve the problem? How can I show the logs showing me the root problem?

*Update December 6, 2023*: The built-in `ftp` command works. I've managed to upload a folder using mput. However, `lftp` is still broken.

`lftp` shows the log after setting the debug level with the command `debug 10` (or any other number between 0 and 10). It seems the connection to the server is lost. Maybe the firewall blocks the server's answer?

```
<--- 450 Transfer aborted. Link to file server lost
```

Answer (score -1):

Switch off passive mode as default.